# php запись в базу поля nvarchar русского текста

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, sql-server

проблема в том что при записи передачи параметров в процедуру с файла php
        var val = "exec [data-site_TO_DB] @tag_time = \'\'\'"+string_time+"\'\'\', @tag_name = \'"+ id +"\', @val = '"+obj.value+"';";

параметр "value" при записи русского текста в базу пишется абракадабра, а английский текст пишется нормально, наверное проблема с кодировкой. Хотелось бы узнать есть решение перекодирования передаваемого значения в процедуру? Потому что изменения кодировки в столбце базы данных не применяется

Comment: Передавайте параметр nvarchar так: N'текст'

Comment: не .. тоже не хочет